# How to get <apex:column> component to play nicely with Bootstrap?

Tags: visualforce, html, css, bootstrap

I've set up a VisualForce page with 7 columns. I've added a pageBlock, a pageBlock table, and 3 apex:columns into the bootstrap columns.

The pageBlock and pageBlock table refresh fine, however the columns stay the same width no matter how big the pageBlockTable is.

I've tried setting `width=100%' but to no avail. How can I get apex:components working nicely inside bootstrap columns?

[image]

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Corporate Sales - Opportunities Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row seven-cols stages">

            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
                <apex:pageBlock title="Hello1">
                      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!$User.FirstName}" var="u">
                          <apex:column headerValue="Test Column 1"/>
                          <apex:column headerValue="Test Column 2"/>                    
                      </apex:pageBlockTable>         
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1" >
                <apex:pageBlock title="Hello2">
                     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!$User.FirstName}" var="u" >
                          <apex:column headerValue="Test Column 1"/>
                          <apex:column headerValue="Test Column 2"/>
                      </apex:pageBlockTable>   
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
                <apex:pageBlock title="Hello3">
                     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!$User.FirstName}" var="u" >
                          <apex:column headerValue="Test Column 1"/>
                          <apex:column headerValue="Test Column 2"/>                 
                      </apex:pageBlockTable>   
                </apex:pageBlock>

            **3 more identical pageblocks**


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
        #header {
            text-align:center;
            margin-bottom:40px;
        }

        .bPageBlock .pbTitle {
            width: 100%;    
            text-align: center;
        }

        .stages {
            text-align:center;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px), @media (min-width: 992px),  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
          .seven-cols .col-md-1,
          .seven-cols .col-sm-1,
          .seven-cols .col-lg-1 {
            width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
            *width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
          }
        }
```

Comment: Could you post your code please? Its really hard to propose something without code

Comment: Problem is that pageblock table is rendered as piece piece of html code inside your dive cell. Of course, you can go deeper to find where to apply some style, but I would suggest to stop using that (As well as you are using bootstrap already) and do a table via divs and apex:repeat. as a result, you will get really good flexible page with clean DOM. But that is my opinion only

Comment: @kurunve Thanks for your help, I've managed to make a table with apex:repeat like you said and it's much easier.

Comment: Can you post your code as an answer then? It would definitely help someone in future I think)